# JS openDatabase fails sometimes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-sql

I call openDatabase function with the following parameters:

```
   db = openDatabase("posapp", "", 'POS WebSql DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
```

It works almost in  99% of cases.

But sometimes it just hangs the tab and no realoing of tab helps anymore.

If I debug it with dev panel eventually  I end up that all process gets stuck and doesn't go further with insruction.

I use Google Chrome  39.0.2171.65 (64-bit).
My OS is Debian GNU/Linux 7  3.2.0-4-amd64

It works fine on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

I know this might not be the answer you want by websql is deprecated.
It might not be supported in browsers moving forward and wasn't (as far as I know) supported in anything other then webkit.

According to can I use

> The Web SQL Database specification is no longer being maintained and support may be dropped in future versions.

If you can use an alternative you might get more consistent results